# ¿Es posible subir archivos de código en las preguntas? ¿Se podría hacer algo al respecto?

Tags: soporte, preguntas

Hace un rato formulé esta pregunta:

[¿Cómo graficar múltiples líneas con ggplot con eje X como variable de tiempo? (ver ejemplo)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149345/c%c3%b3mo-graficar-m%c3%baltiples-l%c3%adneas-con-ggplot-con-eje-x-como-variable-de-tiempo-v)

y dado que mi código es extenso, no lo incluí como parte de la misma. ¿Existe alguna opción para anexarlo o será posible solicitar a los administradores que dicha opción pueda considerarse?

Gracias de antemano por cualquier orientación.

Comment: Hola alejandro. No, no se puede anexar archivos en ninguno de los post de toda la red (que no es solo SO en español). Si tu codigo es extenso, entonces deberias ver la posibilidad de hacer un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable. Para el caso, no son los moderadores los que pedirian ese cambio, si no la comunidad entera (y seria un cambio enorme a todos los sitios y como funcionan)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, no se puede anexar archivos en ninguno de los post de toda la red (que no es solo SO en español). 
Si tu codigo es extenso, entonces deberias ver la posibilidad de hacer un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable (mira por favor [ACA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Para el caso, no son los moderadores los que pedirian ese cambio, si no la comunidad entera (y seria un cambio enorme a todos los sitios y como funcionan).

Los del ejemplo, es asi porque la idea es que tu pregunta pueda ayudar a quienes preguntan en el futuro. Teniendo un escenario basico y estandar que muestra el error, cualquiera con un problema similar puede ver como se soluciono dicho escenario, y de ahi avanzar a tratar de solucionar su problema.